# Cannot load custom bundle in Sylius?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I want to create my own bundles in Sylius. I created in the directory src and named App like that

```
src
   Sylius
        .......
   App
       Bundle
           ShopBundle
                AppShopBundle.php
```

In this file, I wrote very simple:

```
namespace App\Bundle\ShopBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppShopBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

And I registered this bundle in AppKernel.php

```
$bundles = array(
    new App\Bundle\ShopBundle\AppShopBundle()
);
```

But when I run the site, I have an exception. I don't understand the problem here, anyone can help me ?

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 28:
>   Attempted to load class "AppShopBundle" from namespace "App\Bundle\ShopBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for "App\Bundle\ShopBundle\AppShopBundle"?

Answer (score 3):

You should edit composer.json file to autoload your new bundle

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
}
```

Then run composer dump-autoload in terminal

Answer (score 3):

Tuan's approach worked for me. In my case my composer.json autoload equals:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-0": { "Sylius\\": "src/", "App\\": "src/" }
},
```

and then you'll want to clear cache after running 'composer dump-autoload'

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

Answer (score 0):

While Tuan's answer will work, it uses `psr-0`. Adding an updated answer for `psr-4` support.

Change your composer.json's autoload configuration to load the whole source directory like so:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
}
```